# Block_timestamp in contract's e2e_tests

Tags: ink

Is it possible to get / set block_timestamp in contract's e2e-tests?

Like [ink::env::test::set_block_timestamp](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_env/test/fn.set_block_timestamp.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it has been added to `ink! 4.1.0` check this [PR](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1721)

`ink::env::test::set_block_timestamp::<ink::env::DefaultEnvironment>(10056465);`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken that is only for normal tests?